# Practical/heuristic algorithm for multi set-cover

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms, heuristics

Consider a universe $N$ containing $n$ elements, and a collection of sets $\mathcal{C}$, over $N$. The $k$-multiset multicover (MSMC) problem is to cover all elements of the universe $N$ at least $k$ number of times using minimum number of sets from $\mathcal{C}$. (When $k=1$, the problem reduces to min-set cover).

Are there any heuristics out there with 'good' performance on 'real' data for $n=1000$ and $|\mathcal{C}| = 1000$?

Comment: Have you tried formulating this as an ILP and running off the shelf solvers?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to tweak the limits (in particular `max_level` may be too low), but for at least some "real" problems this is within the bounds of Knuth's [algorithm M](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/dlx3.w).

See also

- The documentation of [algorithm D](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/dlx1.w), which describes the basic file format; the documentation of algorithm M just explains the changes made to generalise it;
- the [latest preprint](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5c.ps.gz) of fascicle 5c of *The Art of Computer Programming*, which at some point will get as far as explaining the algorithm, but already has a number of exercises that will give you an idea of the problems that Knuth has solved with it.